# After Hitagi End, does Nadeko ever meet Araragi again?

Tags: monogatari-series

So in Hitagi End, Deishuu then told Koyomi Araragi to stay out of Nadeko's life from then on. I'm wondering if Araragi ever meets Nadeko after that? (time-order, not release-order)(This is a light novel related question)

Answer (score 1):

Off the top of my head... They meet in (happends after Hitagi End) Zoku-Owari. But that is kind of cheating. They may of possibily met in Off-Season... But I haven't gotten around to reading through the rest of the books. Then of course there is the new season...

Comment: Yeah I don't think meeting in another world count ...